# How to add custom YoY field to output?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to determine **the YoY growth by month, 2017 to 2018, for number of Company bookings per property**.

I've tried casting and windowed functions but am not obtaining the correct result.

#### Example Table 1: Bookings

```
    BookID  Amnt  BookType  InDate  OutDate  PropertyID  Name  Status
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    789555 $1000  Company  1/1/2018  3/1/2018  22111   Wendy   Active       
    478141 $1250   Owner   1/1/2017  2/1/2017  35825   John  Cancelled
```

There are only two book types (e.g., Company, Owner) and two Book Status (e.g., Active and Cancelled).

#### Example Table 2: Properties

```
   Property ID    State    Property Start Date    Property End Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   33111         New York       2/3/2017                
   35825         Michigan       7/21/2016
```

The Property End Date is blank when the company still owns it.

#### Example Table 3: Months

```
   Start of Month          End of Month
-------------------------------------------
    1/1/2018                1/31/2018
```

The previous developer created this table which includes a row for each month from 2015-2020.

I've tried many various iterations of my current code and can't even come close.

#### Desired Outcome

I need to find the YoY growth by month, 2017 to 2018, for number of Company bookings per property. The stakeholder has requested the output to have the below columns:

```
Month Name  Bookings_Per_Property_2017  Bookings_Per_Property_2018  YoY                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The number of Company bookings per property in a month should be calculated by counting the total number of active Company bookings made in a month divided by the total number of properties active in the month.

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that should be close to what you need. It works by:

- `LEFT JOIN`ing the three tables; the important part is to properly check the overlaps in date ranges between `months(StartOfMonth, EndOfMonth)`, `bookings(InDate, OutDate)` and `properties(PropertyStartDate, PropertyEndDate)`: you can have a look at [this reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) for general discussion on how to proceed efficiently
- aggregating by month, and using conditional `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to count the number of properties and bookings in each month and year. The logic implicitly relies on the fact that this aggregate function ignores `NULL` values. Since we are using `LEFT JOIN`s, we also need to handle the possibility that a denominator could have a `0` value.

Notes:

- you did not provide expected results so this cannot be tested
- also, you did not explain how to compute the `YoY` column, so I left it alone; I assume that you can easily compute it from the other columns

Query:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(m.StartOfMonth) AS [Month],
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(StartOfMonth) = 2017 THEN b.BookID END) 
        / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(StartOfMonth) = 2017 THEN p.PropertyID END), 0) 
        AS Bookings_Per_Property_2017,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(StartOfMonth) = 2018 THEN b.BookID END) 
        / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(StartOfMonth) = 2018 THEN p.PropertyID END), 0) 
        AS Bookings_Per_Property_2018
FROM months m
LEFT JOIN bookings b
    ON  m.StartOfMonth <= b.OutDate 
    AND m.EndOfMonth   >= b.InDate
    AND b.status = 'Active'
    AND b.BookType = 'Company'
LEFT JOIN properties p
    ON  m.StartOfMonth <= COLAESCE(p.PropertyEndDate, m.StartOfMonth)
    AND m.EndOfMonth   >= p.PropertyStartDate
GROUP BY MONTH(m.StartOfMonth)
```